# iOS 8 widget icon is missing for first time after installation

Tags: ios8, ios8-today-widget

The widget icon in Today section is missing for first time after installation.After that the icon is showing properly.I am using 8.1.1 iPhone 6 device.

Comment: The same issue exist in many apps including Yahoo's News Digest

Comment: Any update on this? Happens for two totally different apps. Still don't know  how to fix it.

Comment: I tried all suggestions posted but still not fixed.i think its a bug from iOS side.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you got the "App Icon Source" pointing to the right AppIcon assets. You can find this option under "General" in your project target for your today extension.

If everything is right, you should be able to see the icon by removing the app widget from the "today" drop-down and adding it back in with the "Edit" button at the bottom of the drop-down

Answer (score 3):

You have to make sure your icon target is set for both your app and widget. Go to Images.xcassets and add your widget to the 'Target Membership'

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the Settings/Spotlight icons in your assets file, it won't show. Its best practice to add them anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove app when widget is enable.
2.Install your app again.
3.In Some iOS Version has a higher risk of  widget icon is gone.

Do test in different Version
It is ok：  iOS 8.0.2、iOS 9.0 and later

Has Problem version:  iOS 8.4.1、 iOS 8.3
(maybe in 8.1.1 ~ 8.4.1 has problem)

you can do the same test in other OS vesion

Answer (score 0):

in target
select

```
( widget )
```

and change
( deployment target ) to iOS 8 , 9 , ,,,,,

welcome ...

Answer (score -2):

go to project select your widget target, in App icons and launch images select use asset catalogs, and in build settings tab "asset catalog compiler -options" set the "asset catalog app icon set name" accordingly.

hope it will work